# displaying popped values as any other digit and not shifting them up

Tags: arrays, c++11, stack

i am trying to make a program on implementing a sack as an array.
consider the following output:
current condition of stack : ->5
                               6
                               7
element popped : 5
current condition of stack : ->6
                               7

element popped : 6
current condition of stack : ->7

***how i want the output to be :***

current condition of stack : ->5
                               6
                               7
element popped : 5
current condition of stack : ->0     //or any other digit/character
                               6
                               7

element popped : 6
current condition of stack : ->0
                               0
                               7

please dont worry about the positioning of the arrow(in the output)

**i really couldnt write the output(as written above) in the way it actually appears on the screen(stackoveflow wudnt let me)  sorry for the inconvenience.
the numbers for the output appear in the immediate next line(using \n )

here goes the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int Pop(int[], int&);
int Push(int[], int&, int);
void Display(int[], int);


void main()
{
    const int size = 50;
    int stack[size];
    int item, top = -1, res;
    char ch = 'y';
    while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "\n Enter item for insertion into stack : ";
        cin >> item;
        res = Push(stack, top, item);
        if (res == -1)
        {
            cout << "\n Stack overflow encountered!";
            _getch();
        }
        cout << "\n Now, the stack after insertion is : "<<"\n";
        Display(stack, top);
        cout << "\n Do you wish to enter more elements into the stack? (y/n) 
: ";
        cin >> ch;
    }
    cout << "\n The deletion of the elements inserted previously begins now 
: ";
    ch = 'y';
    while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
    {
        res = Pop(stack, top);
        if (res == -1)
        {
            cout << "\n Stack underflow encountered!";
            _getch();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n The deleted element is : " << res << endl;
            cout << "\n Now, the stack after deletion is : "<<"\n";
            Display(stack, top);
        }
        cout << "\n Do you wish to delete more elements from the stack? 
(y/n) : ";
        cin >> ch;
    }
    _getch();
    return;
}

int Push(int stack[], int&top, int ele)
{
    const int size = 50;
    if (top == size - 1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    else
    {
        top++;
        stack[top] = ele;
    }
    return 0;
}

int Pop(int stack[], int&top)
{
    int ret;
    if (top == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = stack[top];              //this is the deleted element from 
the stack which will be displayed ahead
        top--;
    }
    return ret;
}

void Display(int stack[], int top)
{
    if (top == -1)
    {
        return ;
    }
    cout << stack[top] << "<---" <<endl;
    for (int i = top - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << stack[i] << endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: To display `0 0 7`, it's not enough to keep track of the current size of the stack (which you do in `top`), but also the high water mark - the largest size the stack has ever had. Then just have `Display` print `hwm-top` zeros in front.

Comment: thanks igor, but i am a beginner, a real beginner, i really couldnt understand almost all of what you said. can you suggest some additional changes in the following functions : int pop() and display(){ the function definitions} maybe some changes in the logic which i have used to display the elements of the stack.

Comment: I'm not going to do your homework for you, if that's what you are asking. Consider: when you say you want to print `0 0 7` - why three digits, specifically? Why not one (the actual number of elements in the stack at the time) or 50 (the size of the storage allocated for the stack)? Where would the number "three" come from? Once you formulate an answer to this question, chances are high you would understand how to implement it.

Comment: oh okay, thats what you meant, i misinterpreted it. the zeroes are to be displayed just to highlight the fact, that the zeroes actually had some elements in their place(before deletion) and now, just to symbolically tell a user that a particular element has been deleted, i am trying to have a zero to be displayed. the number of zeroes just implies that that particular amount of elements were there in the stack initially. sorry if you found the question to be a homework, i really missed out on clarifying the exact issue.

Comment: Right, so you need to keep track of the largest number of elements the stack has had at any point (also known as [high water mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_water_mark)). Think about how you would do that. Once you have that, the difference between this high water mark and `top` is precisely how many zeros you would need to print in front.

Comment: That helps, thanks very much Igor.